# How to generate CSS3 gradient background

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website from a PSD. In a section, I've seen that there are a mixed background color. I think It'll be a best way to match the color if I can use CSS3 gradient. But, I can't use CSS3 gradient. So, I took a help of "online CSS3 gradient background generator from image". Look, I want code for this background image:
[image]

But, from the online generator I've got this:
[image]

Look, the two images aren't same. There are a huge white color on the 1st image at the almost left to right which is absent in the 2nd image. Take a look please, the first image again:
[image]

I've used this [online generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) by uploading image and copy-paste the CSS code which it provided:

[image]

You can check the result at this link test link too: http://abidhasan.zxq.net/test/

**So, how can I get the perfect CSS3 and cross-browser compatible code for the first image of this question?**

The actual section of the PSD is:
[image]

Isn't the CSS3 gradient best and shortest way to make the background of that section?

Comment: It looks to me that in the generator you have it set for a linear gradient. Try switching it to a radial gradient.

Comment: Yes, a CSS gradient is the best and shortest way to make the background. It looks like you've found a bug in the gradient generator tool you're using; you may want to report it to them. In the meanwhile, your best bet might be to simply drag the handles around in the generator manually until you get a gradient that looks like what you want.

Comment: http://www.css3files.com/gradient/   radial gradient

Comment: How can I report to them? the saved link of the conversion is: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#d0d0d0+0,cacaca+1,cacaca+2,dfdfdf+9,e1e1e1+12,e4e4e4+13,e4e4e4+98,dbdbdb+99,cfcfcf+99,c6c6c6+100,c4c4c4+100;Custom

Comment: Basically, doing it manually is so painful to me right now. Is there another web tool who give the facility of generating gradient code from uploading image?

Answer (score 0):

I used [ColorZilla's Gradient Editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) and the ColorZilla Chrome extension in order to find the upper and lower bounds of the gradients you posted.  Then I used the CSS rule sets generated by the gradient editor to make two div elements.  I nested one inside of the other, and gave the inner div `opacity: .5`.

HTML:

```
<div class="gradient" style="width: 400px; height: 100px;">
    <div class="topGradient" style="width: 400px; height: 100px;  opacity: 0.5"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.topGradient {
    background: rgb(204,204,204); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(204,204,204,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 22%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(204,204,204,1)), color-stop(22%,rgba(255,255,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(204,204,204,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 22%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(204,204,204,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 22%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(204,204,204,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 22%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(204,204,204,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 22%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.gradient {
    background: rgb(224,224,224); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(224,224,224,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 35%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(224,224,224,1)), color-stop(35%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(204,204,204,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(224,224,224,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 35%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(224,224,224,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 35%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(224,224,224,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 35%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(224,224,224,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 35%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e0e0e0', endColorstr='#cccccc',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

The end result was this:

[image]

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/208dzg37/).